# ROS2 Industrial on Physical Hardware

Tags: ros2, robotic-arm, ros-industrial, fanuc

I'm trying to use ROS2 to control a Fanuc CRX25ia arm.  Following the Industrial Training docs, I got it working in Melodic, which was the latest version of the fanuc driver, and was planning to port my support, moveit, and the relevant fanuc_driver components to ROS2.  However, the 'Industrial Training' for ros2 is missing the section "Using MoveIt! with Physical Hardware", and trying to port the previous launch file it looks like many of the package's dependencies (`industrial_robot_client`, `industrial_msgs`,`industrial_utils`, `industrial_robot_simulator`, etc) no longer exist in Ros2 industrial.  Are there alternatives, or another way to get the robot interface part working without rewriting those packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some information about this in this issue:

https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_core/issues/253

in particular:

https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_core/issues/253#issuecomment-1726007620

> Thanks to all those that have posted here on this topic. We are
> jointly going to more explicitly line out our strategy relative to
> drivers and comms with manipulators and in parallel update Industrial
> Robot Driver Specification. As Gijs above illuminated there are now
> more OEMs offering external motion interfaces, and now more extensible
> and versionable ways to support ROS 2 interoperability with those
> interfaces, be it via microROS (Yaskawa) or ros2_control (UR). We will
> try to provide the resources to enable OEMs to develop, deploy and
> maintain ROS 2 support, in a way that benefits both developers and
> OEMs and sustains over changes to ROS 2 and to OEM controllers.

It seems like there aren't plans to update `industrial_client`.